# Efficient way to bulk insert / update using typeORM

Tags: database, insert, graphql, typeorm, bulk

How it's possible to insert pre-created objects into relation with an object using TypeORM?
As I know the non-efficient is this(many to many relations):

```
 const tags = await Tag.findByIds(tagIds);
 const todo = await Todo.findOne(todoId);
 todo.tags = tags;
 return await Todo.save(todo)
```

Also `.add()` property of `RelationalQueryBuilder` takes single object or Id as is mentioned in [docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/relational-query-builder.md)

```
await getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .relation(Post, "categories")
    .of(1)
    .add(3);
```

So what is the efficient way to bulk insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had error while using `@Arg` imported from `typeGraphql` for passing an array of string so I resolved it so `add()` from `typeOrm` takes the Id array
so the fast and performant example of relational query is:

```js
import { Resolver, Arg, Mutation } from "type-graphql";
import { Todo } from "../../entity/Todo";
import { createQueryBuilder } from "typeorm";

@Resolver()
export class BulkAssignTagsResolver {
  @Mutation(() => Todo)
  async bulkAssignTodoTag(
    @Arg("tagIds", () => [String]) tagIds: string[],
    @Arg("todoId") todoId: string
  ): Promise<Todo | undefined> {
    await createQueryBuilder("todo")
      .relation(Todo, "tags")
      .of(todoId)
      .add(tagIds);

    return Todo.findOne(todoId, { relations: ["tags"] });
  }
}
```